# How to create a general compare method in c# to compare between a student and a teacher

Tags: c#

I have hierarchy `person`,`student` and `teacher`.

`person` is the base class,and `student` and `teacher` are the derive classes.

`Teacher` have salary and `Student` have `Marks`. I want to implement a general  compare method whether I send the `Student` or `teacher` object.

The compare method compare it and return `true` if `t1.salaray` is greater than `t2.salary` and the same method should compare `s1.marks > s2.marks` if so return `true`.

my code is:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
   public class person
    {
        String name;
       int cnic;

        public String Name
        {    
            get
            {    
                return name;
            }
            set
            {    
                name = value;
            }
        }

        public int Cnic
        {    
            get
            {    
                return cnic;
            }
            set
            {    
                cnic = value;
            }
        }

        public void Marks
        {                
        }      
    }
}

    class student : person
    {
        String rollno;
        double marks;

        public String Rollno
        {
            get
            {    
                return rollno;
            }
            set
            {
                rollno = value;   
            }    
        }

        public double Marks
        {
            get
            {    
                return marks;
            }
            set
            {
                marks = value;    
            }
        }               
    }
}

 class Teacher : person
 {
     int salary;
     public int Salary
     {
         get
            {    
                return salary;
            }
            set
            {
                salary = value;    
            }
        }        
    }
}

**Main class is:** 

 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            student o1 = new student();
            o1.Marks = 78.0;
            o1.Name = "Abuzar";

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Student: 1");
            Console.WriteLine("Name:" + o1.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Marks:" + o1.Marks);
            Console.WriteLine("Roll No:" + o1.Rollno);
            student o2 = new student();
            o2.Marks = 78.0;
            o2.Name = "Abuzar";

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Student: 2");

            Console.WriteLine("Name:" + o2.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Marks:" + o2.Marks);
            Console.WriteLine("Roll No:" + o2.Rollno);
            student o3 = new student();
            o3.Marks = 80.5;
            o3.Name = "Liaqat";
            o3.Rollno = "FA14-BSE-123";
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Student: 3");
            Console.WriteLine("Name:" + o3.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Marks:" + o3.Marks);
            Console.WriteLine("Roll No:" + o3.Rollno);
            student o4 = new student();
            o4.Marks = 74;
            o4.Name = "Mohsin";
            o4.Rollno = "FA14-BSE-123";
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Student: 4");

            Console.WriteLine("Name:" + o4.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Marks:" + o4.Marks);
            Console.WriteLine("Roll No:" + o4.Rollno);
            student o5 = new student();
            o5.Marks = 45.0;
            o5.Name = "Asad";
            o5.Rollno = "FA14-BSE-201";
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Student: 5");
            Console.WriteLine("Name:" + o5.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Marks:" + o5.Marks);
            Console.WriteLine("Roll No:" + o5.Rollno);

            Teacher t1 = new Teacher();
            t1.Name = "Asad Rafiq";
            t1.Salary = 2500;
            t1.Cnic = 17301 - 2568 - 89;
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Teacher: 1");
            Console.WriteLine("Name:" + t1.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Cnic:" + t1.Cnic);
            Console.WriteLine("Salary:" + t1.Salary);

            Teacher t2 = new Teacher();
            t2.Name = "Sara irum";
            t2.Salary = 30000;
            t2.Cnic = 17301 - 2512 - 80;
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Teacher: 2");
            Console.WriteLine("Name:" + t2.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Cnic:" + t2.Cnic);
            Console.WriteLine("Salary:" + t2.Salary);
            Teacher t3 = new Teacher();
            t3.Name = "Sanam Ali";
            t3.Salary = 2500;
            t3.Cnic = 17301 - 2568 - 89;
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Teacher: 3");
            Console.WriteLine("Name:" + t3.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Cnic:" + t3.Cnic);
            Console.WriteLine("Salary:" + t3.Salary);
            Teacher t4 = new Teacher();
            t4.Name = "Abbas khalid";
            t4.Salary = 80000;
            t4.Cnic = 17301 - 2568 - 89;

            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Teacher: 4");
            Console.WriteLine("Name:" + t4.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Cnic:" + t4.Cnic);
            Console.WriteLine("Salary:" + t4.Salary);
            Teacher t5 = new Teacher();
            t5.Name = "Sana Malik";
            t5.Salary = 90000;
            t5.Cnic = 17301 - 2168 - 89;

            Boolean b = o1.Compar(o2);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And where is your problem? Override `object.Equals` in all your classes and with your compare-logic you´re done. Btw.: Please use auto-properties to reduce your code so it gets easier to scroll in the post, so instead of `int MyProp {get { return myValue; } set { myValue = value; }}` use `MyProp { get; set; }`.

Comment: Use GetType to get class name. Student student = new Student();
        Type type = student.GetType();

Comment: where did you declare compar

Comment: For your "best-practice": use capital letter on classes, Student, Person, put the class code in different .cs file, Override the ToString() of each object in order to print information on the object.

Comment: Thanks for helping Capital letters used for clases and i have declaed separate clases for each and i have write in my question in one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this on person class

```
   public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                if (this.marks == ((student)obj).marks)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
```

and do for Teacher class too.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
                {
                    if (this.salary == ((Teacher)obj).salary)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }
```

then compare.

Answer (score 0):

check object as 'object is Student' or 'object is Teacher'.

Answer (score 0):

use the is keyword

```
if(o2 is student)
   {
 //do this 
     }
    else if(o2 is teacher )
   {
    //do this
   }
```

consult the book Pro C# 5.0 and the .net framework for more details

Answer (score 0):

Create a generic method that resembles this:

```
 public bool Comparer<T>(T object1, T object2)
    {
        if (object1 is Student && object2 is Student)
        {
            var student1 = (Student)(object)object1;
            var student2 = (Student)(object)object2;
            return student1.Mark == student2.Mark;
        }
        else if (object1 is Teacher && object2 is Teacher)
        {
            var teacher1 = (Teacher)(object) object1;
            var teacher2 = (Teacher)(object) object2;
            return teacher1.Salary == teacher2.Salary;
        }
        else 
       {
          //... Put your other logic here
       }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool CompareValues(double value1, double value2)
{
    return (value1 > value2);
}

public bool CompareValues(object p1, object p2)
{
    try
    {
        if (p1 is student && p2 is student)
        {
            var student1 = (student)p1;
            var student2 = (student)p2;
            return CompareValues(student1.Marks, student2.Marks);
        }
        else if (p1 is Teacher && p2 is Teacher)
        {
            var teacher1 = (Teacher)p1;
            var teacher2 = (Teacher)p2;
            return CompareValues(teacher1.Salary, teacher2.Salary);
        }
        else
        {
            //can't compare different values
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree with "general" compare. Since you have different comparison method per derived person, the compare should be specific to that class. Therefore implement/ override the comparison methods for each classes.

For ex: in Teacher class

```
// override the object comparison function: Equals
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if(obj == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(obj is Teacher)
    {
        return this.Salary == ((Teacher)obj).Salary;
    }
    return base.Compare(obj); // most likely to be false...
}
// Overriding GetHashCode is necessary to override the Equals function
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return base.GetHashCode();
}

// override the < <= > >= == != operators
public static bool operator <(Teacher t1, Teacher t2) 
{
    return t1.Salary < t2.Salary;
}
public static bool operator >(Teacher t1, Teacher t2) 
{
    return t1.Salary > t2.Salary;
}
public static bool operator <=(Teacher t1, Teacher t2) 
{
    return t1.Salary <= t2.Salary;
}
public static bool operator >=(Teacher t1, Teacher t2) 
{
    return t1.Salary < t2.Salary;
}
public static bool operator ==(Teacher t1, Teacher t2) 
{
    return t1.Salary == t2.Salary;
}
public static bool operator !=(Teacher t1, Teacher t2) 
{
    return t1.Salary != t2.Salary;
}
```

Then in your main you can even use

```
bool doesTeacher1HaveBiggerSalary = teacher1 > teacher2;
```

Repeat the same for Student class and change the salary to marks.

You might want to consider how you compare the base Person class as well, next time.